# What happens to threads on resume from windows hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, resume

I have a simple program to move the mouse pointer every minute, to avoid the screensaver starting. This is running on a windows laptop.
At night I usually 'hibernate' the laptop and 'resume' in the morning.
On resume the mouse move program is frozen.
I have two questions:

1. What happens to Java threads during the hibernate/resume cycle?
2. How can I modify the program to automatically restart the thread when the laptop has resumed?

The main part of the program is shown below - this is contained in a JavaFX application with a label which I update.

```
        go = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Robot hal = new Robot();
                int sec;
                PointerInfo pi = null;
                while (true) {
                    sec = 60;
                    while (sec > 0) {
                        hal.delay(1000);
                        pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                        final Point pObj = pi.getLocation();
                        final int sec2 = sec;
                        Platform.runLater(() -> lab.setText(String.format("%2d %4d %4d", sec2, pObj.x, pObj.y)));
                        sec = sec - 1;
                    }
                    hal.mouseMove(pi.getLocation().x + 1, pi.getLocation().y + 1);

                }
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MouseMoverFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    go.start();
```

Comment: Shouldn't disabling the screensaver be the ideal solution?

Comment: Your second question assumes that the thread gets stopped when hibernation occurs, but your first question indicates that you don't know what happens. Why don't you just test what happens?

Comment: To understand that you could analyse what's the state of your threads on resume - get a thread dump of your app to check the states, so you can decide on a solution.

Comment: What does the implementation of hal.delay() look like?

Comment: It just wraps Thread.sleep(ms)